# How to Assign on demand CSS Styles to some div or class?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Classifieds/Ads Page for a client using content from a specific Database. I'm close to get the look I'm looking for but now I have a problem. I don't want CSS Styles for the empty boxes to the available spaces.I just want the CSS Styles on the ones that will appear once the information arrive to the database and it's ready to show on the Classifieds/Ads page.

Is there a way to have a CSS style that only is applied when content is present?

[This is my test page.](http://www.albertkinng.com/classifieds/classifieds/index.php)

notice how I kind of cheated the CSS style so the blank boxes (spaces) show a text saying: "place your ad here!" but I really don't want those blank boxes there. Any help will be apreciate!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Why not just use Javascript to create boxes you have data for?

Comment: I need to know how you load your content to help you more, but the first thing that comes to mind is to add some class `has-content` to your `<li>` elements when they get loaded up, and set them `display:none;` if they dont have that class

Comment: my data is coming from my server (MySQL database) your solution sounds good but I don't know how to implement it. Do I need to create a CSS code for the <li> ? oh, I'm not good at javascript yet. still learning everyday. thanks for answering that fast!

Comment: How are you bringing that data from sql, and how are you filling the `<li>` elements? Could you post your javascript/php code? (If it is php you are using to bring data from sql)

Comment: @AlbertKinng Assuming that server side rendering is OK, I'd recommend a foreach loop in your PHP code for each <li></li> block.  You can save some bytes over the wire if you don't send a bunch of unused blocks.

Comment: ok, I don't think I'm understanding what you are asking me here. In my server I go to MySQL Database control panel and created a table with some fields and attributes and etc etc... then I assign those field names to my php page to show the content. what code do you want? the css code I'm using to apply the styles or the database code (the one that have my database name and password and all that??)

Comment: @axlj ok. what do I need to put on the <li> ? I mean how I create a foreach loop?

Comment: @AlbertKinng The scope of this question is pretty huge, so I'll point you to a quick tutorial that I found on google: http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/09/php-mysql-tutorial/.  It will answer the question that I think you meant to ask.  The answer that zero point provided is an excellent solution to the question you actually asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to find the parent div which does not have content on its header (for instance) using jQuery. Then you can set its `display` property to `none`. I have created a working example [****HERE****](https://jsfiddle.net/eyw6y4oo/2/)

**HTML**:

```
 class="ad">
  <h2>This is an ad</h2>
  <p>this is the ad which has been added by the database</p>
</div>
<div class="ad">
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
h2, p {margin:0; padding:0;}

.ad {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height:300px;
  width:130px;
  background: #999;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
  $(".ad").each(function() {
     if ($(this).find("h2").text() == "") {
       $(this).css("display","none");
     };
  })
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!! OMG! I Wish I have your knowledge! Here is the page now: [link](http://www.albertkinng.com/classifieds/classifieds/index.php)

Comment: @AlbertKinng: You're welcome. You will gain the knowledge you wish for over the course of time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of a backend issue than a CSS one. Your php script shouldn't be outputting html for ads that don't exist.